# How to use Proxy<T> with a different type than T as argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm in a situation where I want to use `Proxy`, to "load balance" between a list of class.

A naive example of what I'm trying to do is the following :

```
class Foo {
    constructor(private msg: string) {}

    foo() {
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
}

// @ts-ignore
const proxy: Foo = new Proxy([new Foo('foo'), new Foo('bar')], {
    get: (o, key) => {
        const client = o[Math.floor(Math.random() * o.length)];
        console.log(client, key);
        return client[key];
    },
});
proxy.foo();
```

This "works". The problem is that I'm using typescript. And, due to the `Proxy` type definition we can't do something like

```
new Proxy<Foo>([new Foo(), new Foo()], handler)
```

as it produce the following error :

> Argument of type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.

Is there a way to achieve this ; without loosing type checking ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to change the existing definitions, you can just augment them.

If you are using a module system, you need to redeclare the `ProxyConstructor` in global for it to work:

```
declare global  {
    interface ProxyConstructor {
        new <TSource extends object, TTarget extends object>(target: TSource, handler: ProxyHandler<TSource>): TTarget;
    }
}


const proxy: Foo = new Proxy<Foo[], Foo>([new Foo('foo'), new Foo('bar')], {
    get: (o, key) => {
        const client = o[Math.floor(Math.random() * o.length)];
        console.log(client, key);
        return client[key];
    },
});
proxy.foo();
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know wrapping the typedef into `declare global` would merge them instead of overriding.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution is to create a factory like this:

```
function balance<T>(instances: Array<T>): T {
  return new Proxy<any>({}, {
    get: (o, key) => {
        const client = instances[Math.floor(Math.random() * instances.length)];
        console.log(client, key);
        return client[key];
    },
  }) as T;
}

const proxy = balance([new Foo('foo'), new Foo('bar')]);
proxy.foo();
```

That way you have a reusable and typesafe balancer without compromising any declaration.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Which part of the code gets changed? Please keep in mind that the solution encapsulates the implementation and communicates your intent, something the other solutions don't do. Even if your original solution was possible in TypeScript I would encourage you not to use it directly. Trust me on this.

Comment: it changes from `new Proxy(list)` to `balance(list)` by adding a closure. I like the idea. But I think `new Proxy<Client, Client[]>()` is clear enough. And if I wanted more reusability, I'd subclass `Proxy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `Proxy` type definition to allow a different type from it's parameter type.

```
interface ProxyConstructor {
    revocable<T extends object, S extends object>(
        target: T,
        handler: ProxyHandler<S>,
    ): { proxy: T; revoke: () => void };
    new <T extends object>(target: T, handler: ProxyHandler<T>): T;
    new <T extends object, S extends object>(target: S, handler: ProxyHandler<S>): T;
}
declare var Proxy: ProxyConstructor;
```

Then modify your `Proxy` usage to the following :

```
const proxy: Foo = new Proxy<Foo, Foo[]>([new Foo('foo'), new Foo('bar')], {
    get: (o, key) => {
        const client = o[Math.floor(Math.random() * o.length)];
        console.log(client, key);
        return client[key];
    },
});
```

Comment: have you found any other way to achieve this without updating the definition